# Why are certain things able to get through ufw firewall?

Tags: networking, server, firewall

I should say up-front that I am TOTALLY new to Linux, Ubuntu, and the technical side of networking.  I am setting up Ubuntu on a server computer and have learned a bit about configuring the `ufw` firewall. I have set ufw to block all ports by default (`sudo ufw default deny`) and so far have added rules to open a couple of ports for SSH and game servers, but there is one thing I don't understand.

- How is it that I am still able to update packages, ping IP addresses, etc. 
  if ufw is supposedly blocking all (or almost all) of the ports?
- Does ufw automatically allow traffic back from an IP address that I have connected to?

I'm sure there is a simple technical explanation but I'm having trouble finding it via Google.
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you've set up `ufw` to default-deny *outgoing* connections (which is *not* the default), then applications on your system can connect to external hosts. The connections made to external hosts are generally bidirectional - when you run, say, `curl` or `apt-get`, the programs make a connection to the remote host and can then both push data out and pull data down that connection.

`ufw` is set to default-accept outgoing connections because default-deny is basically the same as not being connected to the network. Depending on what you're trying to secure, though, default-deny outgoing might be the right policy.